# Why would oil be leaking from radiator?

Tags: oil-leak, chrysler

Car is 98' Chrysler Concorde and oil has started flooding out of the radiator. Found a crack in the oil cooler hose and changed that but it still Will not hold the oil

Answer (score 1):

Embedded in your cooling system radiator is a transmission oil cooler, it comes as part of the radiator. From your description, "... **oil** flooding out..." it would appear that your oil cooler has burst/split, and is pumping transmission oil out onto the floor. If this is so it  will mean a replacement radiator/oil cooler assembly.

Comment: Also a complete and thorough transmission flush - if transmission fluid's getting out while the car's running (fluid is pressurized), coolant's getting IN while the car's NOT running (fluid NOT pressurized, but hot cooling system pressurized).